# Android/iOS Test Automation: How to simulate complex gestures

Tags: android, ios, testing, automation, gesture

Is there a Test Automation framework (for iOS/Android/multi-platform), that doesn't require access to the tested application's source code, that supports the ability to simulate complex gestures such as curved drag motions?

I see that most frameworks support the ability for point to point linear gestures, but I require non-linear motions.

Answer (score 0):

On Android there is the [Instrumentation API](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation) with which you can send arbitrary MotionEvents to your own Activities and Views. Check out the [Instrumentation Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html). In particular the `sendPointerSync(MotionEvent me)` method. With that method you can send a series of motion events that represent whatever guesture you want.

Easiest way might be to set up a simple app to "record" motion events for you using a touch listener and store them in some way that you can then feed them in to the `sendPointerSync()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although your solution is valid, unfortunately, I do not have access to the source code for the application that is being tested (Limited number of developer licenses). I do know that many of these automated testing frameworks work on simply supplying the .apk file for the application. I guess I should have been more specific in my original question.

Comment: @imanoob check in to the [MonkeyRunner API](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) I have not personally used it, but looks like it might be helpful for your situation.